# Error - AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'sum'

Tags: python, keras

I'm using the following helper functions to compute Precision, Recall and F1-Score:

```
def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

def f1_m(y_true, y_pred):
    precision = precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
```

I have tried the following imports for Keras:

```
import keras as K
import keras
```

But I get the error:

> in f1_m(y_true, y_pred)
> 12
> 13 def f1_m(y_true, y_pred):
> ---> 14     precision = precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
> 15     recall = recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
> 16     return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
>
> in precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
> 6
> 7 def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
> ----> 8     true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
> 9     predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
> 10     precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
>
> AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'sum'

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Either  use

```
Import keras.backend as K
```

or

```
Import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
```

instead of

```
import keras as K # keras has no direct attribute sum
```

reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible method to solve this:

Import the following:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
```

Instead of these:

```
import keras as K
import keras
```

Comment: If you make this change now it looks like you are mixing imports between keras and tf.keras. Which is a bad idea and it is not supported.